# Select Files containing a certain substring in MSBuild

Tags: msbuild

Suppose I have a bunch of files in a folder:

```
foo.test.txt
bar.txt
...
```

And I want to create an ItemGroup to exclude files containing ".test." somewhere in the title, how would I do that in MSBuild?

```
<!-- Can't change this part -->
<Items Include="*.txt" />

<CreateItem Include="@(Items)" Condition="'%(Items.Exclude)'!='true' AND (???)">
  <Output TaskParameter="Include" ItemName="ItemsToProcess"/>
</CreateItem>
```

Where the ??? should be something like:

```
!Contains(%(Items), ".test.")
```

Except that I don't know how to do that in MSBuild.

Comment: Have you tried **.*test*? not sure if that's msbuild or team build.

No sure why SO is not showing 2 asterisks preceding *test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

KMoraz is off to a good start, but since MSBuild 3.5 you can just use the ItemGroup syntax even inside of targets. So that would be something like:

```
<Project ...>
    <ItemGroup>
        <Items Include="*" Exclude="*.text.*"/>
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Very close except that, unfortunately, I can't edit the <Items /> declaration (as specified in the original question). Sorry I wasn't more clear about that. But that would definitely work otherwise...

Comment: The solution was to basically do this except create a new set of items and use this new collection instead. It turns out that CreateItem doesn't respect Exclude and Condition. So I create a new ItemGroup using exclude like you have here then put a condition on CreateItem like the previous answer suggests. So it was a combination of the two... thanks everyone!

Answer (score 3):

How about using `Exclude`:

```
<CreateItem Include="@(Items)" Exclude="*test*" >
  <Output TaskParameter="Include" ItemName="ItemsToProcess"/>
</CreateItem>
```

Comment: I haven't tried it yet but it's so obvious I have pre-emptively smacked my forehead and said "doh!". Thanks.